# C++ undefined reference to library functions

Tags: c++, makefile, c++14, gnu-make, ld

I have a "small" graphics library I'm building, and I'm running into this error when attempting to build a test binary that links against it:

```
al_test.o: In function `test_wave()':
al_test.cpp:(.text+0x1a7): undefined reference to `min::wave::wave(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
...
```

(and other, similar errors, but we'll focus on this one). The library is built in a makefile with the following rules:

```
all: libmgl.a libmgl.so

libmgl.so: $(OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $* $(LDFLAGS) -shared -o $@

libmgl.a: $(OBJECTS)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) libmgl.a $^

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c -o $@ $<
```

`CXXFLAGS` contains a few things, but most importantly `-std=c++14 -O3 -Wall -Werror` and all of the objects compile just fine and the static and dynamic libraries are output without error or warning.

Now I have a file `source/test/al_test.cpp` meant to test *only* the audio portions of the library that looks something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "twave.h"
int main()
{
    try
    {
        bool out = true;
        out = out && test_wave();
        // out = out && test_ogg();
        // out = out && test_sound_buffer();
        if (out)
        {
            std::cout << "Sound tests passed!" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception &ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Sound tests failed!" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```

and the function `test_wave` is defined in `twave.h` like this:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include "min/wave.h"
bool test_wave()
{
    bool out = true;

    // Load invention wav file
    {
        const min::wave sound = min::wave("data/sound/invention_no_1.wav");

        // File should not be mono
        out = out && !sound.is_mono();
        if (!out)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed wave file not is_mono");
        }

        // Other checks that aren't important...
    }

    return out;
}
```

So here's my problem: `min::wave::wave()` definitely exists and definitely ought to be in the library. Here's a stripped-down `min/wave.h`:

```
#ifndef __WAVE__
#define __WAVE__
#include <string>
namespace min {
class wave
{
  private:
    void load(const std::string);
  public:
    wave(const std::string&);
};
}
#endif
```

and `min/wave.cpp`

```
#include "wave.h"

min::wave::wave(const std::string &file)
{
    load(file);
}

// Definition of `load` omitted; I don't think it's important,
// but know that it is here
```

So the file exists, the function declaration and definition both exist, and I can see in my `make` output that `wave.o` is being built and linked/archived into `libmgl.a`/`libmgl.so`. Yet the compiler claims it doesn't exist. It doesn't seem to be a link order problem; here's my process for building the tests:

```
g++ -c -Imin/ al_test.cpp -o al_test.o
g++ al_test.o -L. -lmgl -lX11 -lGL -lfreetype -lopenal -lvorbisfile -o bin/al_test
```

`mgl` is obviously the name of my library, and those are the other things on which it depends. I also tried replacing `-L.` with `-L/absolute/path/to/project/directory/`, to no avail.

Why does g++ think my function is undefined?

### `nm` commands

By popular demand, here are a few `nm` commands and their outputs:

the static library:

```
nm -C libmgl.a | grep wave
wavefront.o
wave.o:
0000000000000090 T min::wave::load(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)
0000000000000000 W void min::wave::load<min::mem_file>(min::mem_file const&)
0000000000000000 W void min::wave::load<std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > >(std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > const&)
0000000000000000 T min::wave::clear()
0000000000000880 T min::wave::wave(min::mem_file const&)
0000000000000720 T min::wave::wave(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
0000000000000880 T min::wave::wave(min::mem_file const&)
0000000000000720 T min::wave::wave(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
0000000000000080 T min::wave::get_sample_rate() const
0000000000000060 T min::wave::get_data_samples() const
0000000000000050 T min::wave::get_bits_per_sample() const
0000000000000040 T min::wave::data() const
0000000000000020 T min::wave::is_mono() const
0000000000000030 T min::wave::is_stereo() const
0000000000000550 T min::sound_buffer::add_wave_pcm(min::wave const&)
                 U min::wave::get_sample_rate() const
                 U min::wave::get_bits_per_sample() const
                 U min::wave::data() const
                 U min::wave::is_stereo() const
```

...the dynamic library:

```
nm -C libmgl.so
0000000000201020 B __bss_start
0000000000201020 b completed.7631
                 w __cxa_finalize
0000000000000460 t deregister_tm_clones
00000000000004f0 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000200e88 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000201018 d __dso_handle
0000000000200e90 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000201020 D _edata
0000000000201028 B _end
000000000000053c T _fini
0000000000000530 t frame_dummy
0000000000200e80 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
0000000000000548 r __FRAME_END__
0000000000201000 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000000420 T _init
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
00000000000004a0 t register_tm_clones
0000000000201020 d __TMC_END__
```

...and the test file:

```
nm -C al_test.o
                 U __cxa_allocate_exception
                 U __cxa_atexit
                 U __cxa_begin_catch
                 U __cxa_end_catch
                 U __cxa_free_exception
                 U __cxa_throw
                 U __dso_handle
00000000000000e0 t _GLOBAL__sub_I__Z9test_wavev
                 U __gxx_personality_v0
0000000000000000 r .LC1
0000000000000000 T main
                 U __stack_chk_fail
                 U _Unwind_Resume
0000000000000000 T test_wave()
                 U operator delete(void*)
                 U min::wave::wave(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
                 U min::wave::is_mono() const
                 U std::runtime_error::runtime_error(char const*)
                 U std::runtime_error::~runtime_error()
                 U std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)
                 U std::ios_base::Init::Init()
                 U std::ios_base::Init::~Init()
                 U std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::clear(std::_Ios_Iostate)
                 U std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
                 U std::cout
                 U std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)
0000000000000000 b std::__ioinit
                 U typeinfo for std::runtime_error
                 U typeinfo for std::exception
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With more information regarding the symbols available in the static and dynamic libraries, I've come to the conclusion the shared library is empty.

It's empty because `$*` here expand to empty.

> ```
> libmgl.so: $(OBJECTS)
>     $(LD) $* $(LDFLAGS) -shared -o $@
> ```

See [GNU make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#index-_002a-_0028automatic-variable_0029):

> If the target name in an explicit rule does not end with a recognized suffix, ‘$*’ is set to the empty string for that rule.

Replacing `$*` with `$^` like it's used to build libmgl.a should solve your issue.

Comment: This fixed some of my problems (I think) but I'm getting different errors now. I posted a sample in the question comments.

Comment: Wait, I think these may just be issues with my source files (`using namespace <any>;` is evil...). I'll look through them and see what that leaves.

Comment: Okay, I was able to clear up some of the errors by using explicit namespace names on function definitions. However, some errors remain: `./libmgl.so: undefined reference to 'min::vec3<float>::cross(min::vec3<float> const&) const'`. I don't define an explicit overload to that templated function for `float`, so idk what this error means. At any rate, I'm prepared to accept this answer if this new error is unrelated to the one in my question, but idk enough to say whether that's true; do you think it could be related, or is it a separate issue?

Comment: okay, after some intense googling I have determined it's a separate issue related to obscuring template implementations from the translation unit.

Answer (score 1):

Since `nm libmgl.so | grep wave` returns nothing (see comments), we know at least that the library is not linked (built?) correctly.

Indeed, you should invoke `g++` to link it:

```
$(CXX) $* $(LDFLAGS) -shared -o $@
```

Once you've done that, as metioned by user UKMonkey:

> order of linking matters

So, your binary should be built like this:

```
g++ -L. -lmgl -lX11 -lGL -lfreetype -lopenal -lvorbisfile -o bin/al_test al_test.o
```

Comment: I think that `al_test.o` is supposed to be first? I'll try using `g++` instead of `ld` and get back to you.

Comment: @anoneemus No. It is very well at the end. That's how the autotools and CMake write Makefiles ;)

Comment: " you must put dependants first, then the libs that provide the functions after." contradicts that though. al_test requires functions from the library, and that statement seems to say that this means the library must come after. Also, I must point out that I _do_ link to my library, even if not correctly.

Comment: Regardless, I built with `g++` rather than `ld`, and no matter where I put `al_test.o` it still gives me the same error. `nm` now has more output, but still no lines containing "`wave`".

Comment: Well, sure that strange about UK's quote, but sure your .o should be last. The next debugging step is to check what exactly does libmgl contains. What is `$(OBJECTS)` set to?

Comment: I have `OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:cpp=o)` where `$(SOURCES)` expands to all of my source `.cpp` files. I know it has `wave` in it because when my makefile builds `libmgl.so` the line contains `min/wave.o`, and I know it's in the static library because the `ar` command output shows the line `a - min/wave.o`